# How much power can be drawn from the MacBook Pro's 3.5 mm port?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

How much power can be drawn from the MacBook Pro's 3.5 mm audio port?

Is it possible for a device to draw power from it while playing aloud any audio the MacBook may be outputting through it?

Comment: If the device is ordinary headphones, then yes—they use a few milliwatts. But what sort of device are you thinking about?

Comment: The only power which comes from the audio port is the audio signal. No sound? No power. There is not a constant power supply from it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton so a device can't draw any power at all from it unless the computer sends power down it, as it does when playing audio?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The exact amount of power depends on the model of MacBook Pro.

You can usually expect to be able to draw something in the small milliwatt range at best - i.e. something like 10-20 mW for a smart phone audio output, and a laptop perhaps 50-100 mW.

If you happen to have a new MacBook Pro, it is possible to draw a lot more power as it is [specially equipped](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212856) for providing power:

> When you connect headphones with an impedance of less than 150 ohms, the headphone jack provides up to 1.25 volts RMS. For headphones with an impedance of 150 to 1k ohms, the headphone jack delivers 3 volts RMS

And yes, it is theoretically possible to play aloud the audio while drawing the power - but it is not practical. The audio signal basically is the power, so for practical purposes you would try to maximize power output by effectively playing non-music (i.e. basically loud "noise").

Comment: How do you know 10mW?

Comment: @theonlygusti As I replied on your question, could you please tell us a bit about what you intend to use this for? - Then it's possible to give you more details and specifics about what is possible.

Comment: Also be sure to comment with exactly what kind of MacBook Pro you have.

Comment: to power an amp for monitoring a microphone

Comment: Which specific amp? (model)

Comment: And why would you want to do this? - Can you give us some specifics here? - Are you recording the microphone audio on that 3.5 mm audio jack? are you outputting the mix there? - Is it an XLR microphone with phantom power you need to power? - What exactly is the setup - and why can't you just power it like it is usually done with a PSU?

Comment: I don't know yet, I just wanted to know if it's possible to power an amp using the headphone jack

Comment: It would be more convenient to not have to have a separate power supply. I would like to listen to computer output at the same time as my own voice through earphones, as low-latency as possible (software monitoring has too high a latency)

Comment: @theonlygusti It is impossible to answer that question without knowledge of the amplifier. I.e. you can get amplifiers that eats 100s of watts for powering speakers - and you can some that only need a tiny bit of power to power the weakest set of headphones.

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm trying to wrap my head around what you want to do here. First off, it is not practical to power a headphone amplifier through the 3.5 mm jack. Forget that idea again. Do you have an existing audio interface / DAC?

Comment: Usually you would have an external audio interface - you can get very cheap ones on USB for example. It would be able to record the microphone, and you would be able to playback your audio from the computer - and many of these have a button you can press to monitor the microphone in the headphones mixed with the computer playback. It is not software monitoring, so there's no latency issue.

Comment: An amp can never work at 3V?

Comment: Sure - you can amplify with 3V. However, 3V just means "3 volts" - it's the voltage. It doesn't say anything about how much power you can draw. You need to state whether you're talking about building electronics yourself for a hobby amplifier - or you're talking about buying a product on the market.

Comment: Do you know how much power can be drawn then?

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes, that's what I have written in my answer. Note that the noted values are maximums if you output a special loud sound. If you want to playback music, you'll only get fractions of that during quieter parts, and nothing during silence.

Comment: But you just said 3V says nothing about the power....

Comment: Yes, that’s right! - I’m not really sure what is confusing you here? 3V by itself doesn’t say anything about power - you would need to know the number of amps (ampere) as well. When I write about watt in my answer, that is power.

Comment: Therefore you didn't actually say how much power can be drawn in your answer

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is here - the answer says to expect 50-100 mW. That is power. And you still haven’t specified what kind of MBP you have.

Comment: I.e. if you happen to have one of those listed in the answer, you can expect quite a bit more if you have the right kind of impedance. Note that it is Vrms, but then it could theoretically be up to 600 mW.

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212856 (thanks to **@jksoegaard** for the reference in their answer!), the adaptive-impedance audio interface circuit on the new MBP operates in two modes:

1. > When you connect headphones with an impedance of less than 150 ohms, the headphone jack provides up to 1.25 volts RMS.
2. > For headphones with an impedance of 150 to 1k ohms, the headphone jack delivers 3 volts RMS.

From the [basic physics of resistive circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power#Resistive_circuits):

```
P = V^2 / R
```

This means that we can infer the following:

1. In **low-impedance mode**, the best-case voltage is `1.25 Vrms`. Presuming a flat power curve (i.e., the voltage drops accordingly to maintain constant power through a reduced resistance), this means that at `150 Ω` the power delivered into the load is `P = V^2 / R = (1.25 Vrms)^2 / 150 Ω` = **`10.4 mWrms`**. If the power curve is *not* flat then the available power may be higher or lower for lower-impedance loads.
2. In **high-impedance mode**, the voltage is fixed at `3 Vrms`. Maximum power develops through minimum resistance, so at the lower end of the `150-1kΩ` impedance range we have `P = (3 Vrms)^2 / 150 Ω` = **`60 mWrms`**.

In both cases these are optimal parameters derived from a combination of electrical characterizations on Apple's part and a simplified theoretical model on our part. Real-world conditions are not as optimal and will likely see a slight reduction to these maximums.